# How to display a external web page inside a Kendo UI Mobile page without using iFrame

Tags: iframe, kendo-ui

I'm using :

```
   <iframe id="webUIFrame" style="width:100%; min-height: 500px;height: 100%">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
```

with

```
       document.getElementById('webUIFrame').src = myUrl;
```

but it only works on Windows Web Browser instead of mobile web browser, it just show a blank section on mobile.

What should we use to show a page inside a page of Kendo UI Mobile?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this just a webpage, or a mobile app ? If an app, I would use the cordova/phonegap ChildBrowser/InAppBrowser plugin.

Comment: hi @RobinGiltner it's cool control for hybrid app but currently it just support:
"_self" -> opens in the Cordova WebView if strUrl is in the white-list, else it opens in the InAppBrowser 
"_system" -> always open in the system web browser 
"_blank" -> always open in the InAppBrowser 

On my case, I want this external web page loads into a tab or a div.
Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can include  the src into the iframe.

```
<iframe id="webUIFrame" src="http://yoururl.com" style="width:100%; min-height: 500px;height: 100%">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```